# How to style select Material UI height (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm working on a react app with Material Dashboard, and im trying to use a Select (dropbox list), but idk the height is wrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw6te.png)
on the rigth i have a common input and the select style should be like that, but no.
i tried 2 ways
1)

```
<Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
                                    <FormControl fullWidth>
                                        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Price</InputLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                                            id="demo-simple-select"
                                            //value={age}
                                            label="Price"
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                        >
                                            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                                        </Select>
                                    </FormControl>
                                </Box>
```

2. 

```
 <MDInput
                                    select
                                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                                    id="demo-simple-select"
                                    //value={age}
                                    label="Price"
                                    InputProps={{
                                        classes: {root: "select-input-styles"},
                                    }}
                                    fullWidth
                                >
                                    <MenuItem value={10}>No</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={11}>C</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={12}>Vehiculos</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={14}>XD</MenuItem>
                                </MDInput>
```

in both cases the style is not working as it should be

inspecting the element on the browser i noticed that i can solve it modifying the padding from

.css-1cohrqd-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input.MuiSelect-select{display:grid;-webkit-align-items:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;padding:0 0.75rem!important;}

but i can't find that on my project

i want to find the way to fix the height :'v heeeeeelp

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code with the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

with something like this you can change the css of any component:

```
 const selectFieldMui = {
 '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {transformOrigin: 'topright', right: '25px', float: 'right', left: '60px' },
'& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': { textAlign: 'right' },
'& legend': { width: '80px' }
```

}

then in your component you can use const that you defined like this:

```
 <Select sx={selectFieldMui }></Select>
```